# Как подключить проект FBReaderJ к Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle

Пытаюсь подключить проект [FBReaderJ](https://github.com/geometer/FBReaderJ) (использующий C и C++ код) в AndroidStudio.  Получаю следующую ошибку:

> Error:Unable to load class
>   'com.android.build.gradle.managed.BuildType_Impl'. Possible causes for
>   this unexpected error include:
>
> Gradle's dependency cache may be
>   corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
>   ...

Так же видно, что внутри классы не видят переменную R, которая не генерируется .Как мне правильно собрать проект?

Ниже показано, как выглядят мои файлы.
Корневой файл settings.gradle в корне проекта:

```
include ':ambilWarna'
include ':superToasts'
include ':code'
include ':library'
include ':fBReaderJmaster'
```

Корневой файл local.properties:

```
ndk.dir=C\:\\MyPrograms\\AndroidSDK\\ndk-bundle
sdk.dir=C\:\\MyPrograms\\AndroidSDK
```

Корневой файл gradle.properties:

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Корневой файл build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.4.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Так выглядит build.gradle одной из библиотек:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.mobeta.android.dslv"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 19
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
        }
    }

    compileOptions.with {
        sourceCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.txt')
        }
    }

    android.productFlavors {
        create("arm") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi")
        }
        create("arm7") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
        }
        create("arm8") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("arm64-v8a")
        }
        create("x86") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("x86")
        }
        create("x86-64") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("x86_64")
        }
        create("mips") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("mips")
        }
        create("mips-64") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("mips64")
        }
        // To include all cpu architectures, leaves abiFilters empty
        create("all")
    }
}
```

build.gradle основного модуля fBReaderJmaster:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 19
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
        }
    }

    compileOptions.with {
        sourceCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    android.ndk {
        moduleName "DeflatingDecompressor-v3"
cppFlags.addAll(["-I${file("src/main/jni/DeflatingDecompressor")}".toString(),
                         "-I${file("src/main/jni/expat-2.0.1")}".toString(),
                         "-I${file("src/main/jni/LineBreak")}".toString(),
                         "-I${file("src/main/jni/NativeFormats")}".toString()])
        ldLibs.addAll(["android", "EGL", "GLESv2", "dl", "log"])
        stl     = "stlport_static"
    }
    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.txt')
        }
    }

    android.productFlavors {
        create("arm") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi")
        }
        create("arm7") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
        }
        create("arm8") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("arm64-v8a")
        }
        create("x86") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("x86")
        }
        create("x86-64") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("x86_64")
        }
        create("mips") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("mips")
        }
        create("mips-64") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("mips64")
        }
        // To include all cpu architectures, leaves abiFilters empty
        create("all")
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':ambilWarna')
    compile project(':library')
    compile project(':code')
    compile project(':superToasts')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.2.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/json-simple-1.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/LingvoIntegration_2.5.2.12.jar')
    compile files('libs/nanohttpd-2.0.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/open-dictionary-api-1.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/pdfparse.jar')
}
```